# Getting DateDiff from stored procedure with different columns of same columns

Tags: c#, sql

First of all hello, I manage a book store and I want to display my books with publish date and publish remove date. I want to display the days between this two days. For example this is my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spLibrary]
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Tax int, @forwardDate DATETIME

    SET @Tax = 100
    SET @forwardDate = 7

    SELECT 
        b.BookName BookName,
        b.BookAuthor BookAuthor,
        b.BookPrice PriceWithoutTax,
        b.BookPrice + @Tax PriceWithTax,
        b.BookDate PublisDate,
        b.BookDate +  @forwardDate PublishRemoveDate
    FROM
        Book b
END
```

I want to see the difference between PublishDate and PublisRemoveDate. I try but it says multi-identifier error. Can you please help me. Thank a lot from now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new field to your select in your SP

```
GO
alter PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spLibrary]
AS
BEGIN 
declare @Tax int, @forwardDate DATETIME
set @Tax = 100
set @forwardDate = 7

SELECT 
b.BookName BookName,
b.BookAuthor BookAuthor,
b.BookPrice PriceWithoutTax,
b.BookPrice + @Tax  PriceWithTax,
b.BookDate PublisDate,
b.BookDate +  @forwardDate PublishRemoveDate,
datediff(day, BookDate, b.BookDate +  @forwardDate)  as DiffDays 

from 
Book b
END
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to add `@forwardDate` days to `BookDate`. If so, you should declare the variable as an `int`, and then use `dateadd()`:

```
dateadd(day, @forwarDate, BookDate) as PublishRemoveDate
```

On the other hand, if you want the date difference between dates `bookDate` and `PublishRemoveDate`, use `datediff()`:

```
datediff(day, BookDate, PublishRemoveDate) as diff
```

Comment: Thanks it also works. My mainly aim is that to find difference between this two days(PublishRemoveDate and PublishDate) and display on the data as LeftDays.

Comment: I tried but it says invalid column name for PublishRemoveDate . :(